# I need assistance with Batch; "The Syntax of the command is incorrect"

Tags: batch-file

I could not find a solution to this problem, and stackoverflow is the only place I thought I could find a solution. I was creating a batch program to generate a random password. I wanted it to have a Random number of Characters and random letters. Here is the script I used to generate it-

```
set /a rchar=%RANDOM%*8/32768+16
:chargen
set /a charnum=%RANDOM%*36/32768+1
if %charnum%==1 set char='a'
if %charnum%==2 set char='b'
if %charnum%==3 set char='c'
if %charnum%==4 set char='d'
if %charnum%==5 set char='e'
if %charnum%==6 set char='f'
if %charnum%==7 set char='g'
if %charnum%==8 set char='h'
if %charnum%==9 set char='i'
if %charnum%==10 set char='j'
if %charnum%==11 set char='k'
if %charnum%==12 set char='l'
if %charnum%==13 set char='m'
if %charnum%==14 set char='n'
if %charnum%==15 set char='o'
if %charnum%==16 set char='p'
if %charnum%==17 set char='q'
if %charnum%==18 set char='r'
if %charnum%==19 set char='s'
if %charnum%==20 set char='t'
if %charnum%==21 set char='u'
if %charnum%==22 set char='v'
if %charnum%==23 set char='w'
if %charnum%==24 set char='x'
if %charnum%==25 set char='y'
if %charnum%==26 set char='z'
if %charnum%==27 set char='0'
if %charnum%==28 set char='1'
if %charnum%==29 set char='2'
if %charnum%==30 set char='3'
if %charnum%==31 set char='4'
if %charnum%==32 set char='5'
if %charnum%==33 set char='6'
if %charnum%==34 set char='7'
if %charnum%==35 set char='8'
if %charnum%==36 set char='9'
set %char%=%ipassword%
set %fpassword%=%ipassword%%fpassword%
set /a rchar=%rchar%-1
if %rchar%==0 goto :passworddone
goto :chargen
```

I kept getting "The syntax of this error is incorrect" when trying to run it. Does anyone have any ideas for a solution? It would be very much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

First things first, don't use `%` markers on the left of a `set` statement. Something like:

```
set fpassword=xyzzy
set %fpassword%=plugh
```

will set the `xyzzy` variable to be `plugh`, a form of indirection.

It should be:

```
set fpassword=plugh
```

---

Second, there's actually a rather concise (though tricky) method of doing substrings with variable offsets and lengths in `cmd` (something that normally only allows constants) so there's no need for all those `if` statements.

The trick is to call `set` as a sub-function. The following script:

```
@echo off
set string=abcdefgh
set ofs=2
set len=3
rem Here be dragons :-)
call set result=%%string:~%ofs%,%len%%%
echo %result%
```

shows this in action and will output:

```
cde
```

Keep in mind that this is a zero-offset method so you don't want to add `1` to the variable when selecting a random value to use as the index.

---

And lastly, your variable manipulations seem a little off, as you're (for example) trying to set `char` again regardless of the random value chosen, and also doing something torturous with `ipassword` and `fpassword`.

---

Taking all that into account, the script can be better written as something like:

```
@setlocal
@echo off
set /a count = %RANDOM% * 36 / 32768 + 1
set charlist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
set password=
:while1
    set /a index = %RANDOM% * 36 / 32768
    call set char=%%charlist:~%index%,1%%
    set password=%password%%char%
    set /a count = %count% - 1
    if %count% gtr 0 goto :while1

echo %password%
endlocal
```

---

The *other* thing you may want to consider is the password length.   One-character passwords are a very bad idea and I'm not sure *anyone* is going to remember a 36-character password. It may be better to have a password length of (for example) 8 through 12 inclusive:

```
set /a count = %RANDOM% %% 5 + 8
```

(and, yes, that `%%` is the modulo operator - you can use that instead of the multiply/divide actions).